# Magento - How to create links browse by product brand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I want to add several links on home page which individual will lead to special products belonging to same brand, it's like a "browse by brand" functionality, please help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is the way they have implemented brand slider on home page on the [ultimo theme](http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/full_screen_preview/3231798). 
Just show banners/carousel to the brand on home page and add a link to catalogsearch with brand name as query string.   For example, http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=SampleManufacturer Make sure "manufacturer" attribute in backend has "Use in Quick Search" option set to "Yes"